# Como executar WEP API Node e um Projeto ReactJS na mesma máquina?

Tags: node.js, react, localhost

Tenho rodando uma Web API no endereço **localhost:3333** e um Aplicativo ReactJS no endereço **localhost:3000**, no entanto quando tento realizar alguma requisição com [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) o navegador me retorna erro de cors. Existe alguma config para ignorar esse comportamento?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode mudar esse comportamento baixando algumas extensões para o seu navegador, mas no geral é aconselhável que no seu servidor você envie no cabeçalho da resposta o valor `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, existe um middleware do express pra isso.

```sh
$ npm install cors
```

Nas configurações do seu servidor você faz dessa maneira:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```